# How can i add values to trianagle drawcanvas in android?

Tags: android, geometry, android-canvas, draw

I have small problem to put values in the canvas triangle. Please find this images.

wanted image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0uDiLp3seSVbEg2cFVRazA4NDQ/edit?usp=sharing

tried image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0uDiLp3seSVTVVrUTIzOTNJdTQ/edit?usp=sharing

I want to put 10 to 90 values in the triangle canvas and names also. Please give me suggestions how to achieve this. I have tried but i can't get the solution.

Code:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        /*paint.setColor(android.graphics.Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);*/

        paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
        paint.setColor(android.graphics.Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        Point a = new Point(350,300);
        Point b = new Point(50,700);
        Point c = new Point(700,700);

        Path path = new Path();
        path.setFillType(FillType.EVEN_ODD);

        path.moveTo(350,300);
        path.lineTo(b.x, b.y);
        path.lineTo(c.x, c.y);
        path.lineTo(a.x, a.y);
        path.close();

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);



        Paint paint1 = new Paint();

        //paint1.setColor(android.graphics.Color.BLACK);
        //canvas.drawPaint(paint1);

        paint1.setStrokeWidth(4);
        paint1.setColor(android.graphics.Color.YELLOW);
        paint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        paint1.setAntiAlias(true);


        Point a1 = new Point(400,350);
        Point b1 = new Point(140,700);
        Point c1 = new Point(700,700);




        Path path2 = new Path();
        path2.setFillType(FillType.EVEN_ODD);

        path2.moveTo(400,350);
        path2.lineTo(b1.x, b1.y);
        path2.lineTo(c1.x, c1.y);
        path2.lineTo(a1.x, a1.y);
        path2.close();

        canvas.drawPath(path2, paint1);
           }
```